# How many carbons in this skeletal structure?

Tags: organic-chemistry

[image]

How many carbons are in this skeletal structure? I was told to draw a circle at the start of the structure and at each point the line turns off to get the total number of carbons but doing so would result in 6 carbons which I know is wrong but why is it wrong? And where on the structure are the carbons located?

Thanks for clearing this up for me!

Comment: OK, you've described a procedure and immediately told us that it is wrong. How do you know it is wrong?

Comment: Because 6 carbons just looks too many for the size of the structure in my opinion.

Comment: What a weird way of counting the carbons. Just convert all the points where the lines join into a "C", then you should see how many you have.

Comment: So as such this structure should have 3 carbons?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear - this is in addition to the ones that are already shown as "C". What is going on here is that 'terminal' carbons (at the end of a chain) can optionally be shown as element symbols (CH3) - you could equally convert these ones to points, and get just a line drawing.

Comment: Oh, so 6 would be correct after all?

Comment: The IUPAC name is 3-methylpentane. Now, think of how many carbons are there. Actually, I am answering in this way as your question is not clear.
Have you studied about bondline representation of organic compounds? You can find this in books of elementary classes.

Comment: @user55394 yes, there are six carbons in the structure: the three explicitly written ones and three more at the points where lines intersect.

Answer (score 5):

Your intuition is not wrong.

There are indeed 6 carbon atoms in the molecule (3-methyl-pentane).

With bondline/skeletal notation, there's a carbon atom at all the vertices; at the ends, and every time the line changes direction.

Counting the carbon atoms then becomes as simple as counting the vertices.

This becomes more apparent if you explicitly write all the atoms like illustrated below:

[image: 3-methyl-pentane]